# CSS list with multiple columns with horizontal scrolling and automatic column width and height

Tags: javascript, html, css, list, listview

I have an automatically generated list (the number of items and their width are not known beforehand):

```
<div>Page header</div>
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
    ...
    <li>Ninety nine</li>
    <li>One hundred</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div>Page footer</div>
```

and I want the following layout:

```
+-----------------------------------------+
| Page header                             |
|                                         |
| +-------------------------------------+ |
| |One    Five   Nine    Thirteen  .... | |
| |Two    Six    Ten     Fourteen  .... | |
| |Three  Seven  Eleven  Fifteen   Ninet| |
| |Four   Eight  Twelve  Sixteen   One h| |
| <[=======scrollbar=========]----------> |
|                                         |
| Page footer                             |
+-----------------------------------------+ <-- window (viewport) frame
```

so that

- the list fills the window width and window height (except the header and footer height) and automatically resizes when the window resizes,
- the list is scrolled horizontally, with a horizontal scrollbar,
- the number of rows and columns is selected automatically,
- the width of columns is selected automatically by the widest element of the list, or maybe even automatically for each column as the widest element of this column.

I know how to make a similar design for a fixed number of columns, but not for a number of columns automatically adjusting to the screen area.

If the solution is not trivial, maybe there are ready .css or .js that does this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is everything you're looking for. It's done mostly with JQuery to achieve the effect (with some of it in CSS). It is also dynamic so it should handle whatever number of `li`s you have. My explanations for how it works are in the code below:

```
//find the number of li's
var numberOfResults = $('li').length;

//set how many li's you want per row
var numberPerRow = 4;

//pull the first ul for later use
var $firstUL = $('ul');

//divide the number of li's from the number you want per row then round the number
var numberOfRows = Math.ceil(numberOfResults/numberPerRow);

//find the width of the largest li for later use
var maxWidth = Math.max.apply( null, $( 'li' ).map( function () {
  return $( this ).outerWidth( true );
}).get() );

//set container width the width of all rows * the width of each one
$(".container").css({"width": (maxWidth*numberOfRows)+"px"})

//add a ul depending on the number of rows
for(var i=1;i<=numberOfRows;i++){
   $(".container").append('<ul></ul>');
}

// go through each row and add the lis
for(var i=1;i<=numberOfRows;i++){
   $firstUL.find('li:lt('+(numberPerRow)+')').appendTo('ul:eq('+(i)+')');      
}

//loop through all of the lis and set the width to the max
$("li").each(function(){
   $(this).css({"width":maxWidth+"px"})
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/uar5rycb/)

Comment: Thank you! It would be good to calculate the number of rows automatically, onresize, so that the visible part of the list would always cover the whole page (except header and footer).

Answer (score 1):

You ask for the list to fill the window width, but you say it should scroll horizontally with a horizontal scrollbar. These are mutually exclusive. It it fits the window width there should be no horizontal scrollbar. Horizontal scrollbars are bad by design, anyway, though vertical is OK.

What you can do is populate an HTML table, then cycle through the rows and cells examining the widths to see what you have. Following that you can repopulate the table with a different number of cells per row or width per column. Maybe you can do this two or three times, but that seems cludgy to me. There is no automatic function to do this. What I suggest is use a best fit cell width as a constant, which you arrive at through trial and error, and use the CSS attribute to throw away overflow content when that occurs.

Answer (score 0):

To have the list automatically expand to fit the width of the window, you can use the following CSS, with the knowledge that you might need to expand other parent elements and set `margin: 0` and `padding: 0`

```
width: 100%;
```

---

To make the list scroll when too big for the screen, try using the following CSS style

```
overflow-x: scroll
```

or if you need the list to scroll in both directions when too big, use this

```
overflow: scroll
```